# How to add/display all the sub elements of an element in MarkLogic Harmonization

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I am using DataHub in harmonizing my `Entity` data.

I am trying to get the child of my element `StatusHistory`. However, with my current code below, only one instance of the child is being displayed. The `StatusHistory` currently has atleast more than 5 records / child.

The goal is to do add/display all the child under the `StatusHistory`.

Below is my current code in content.sjs

```js
function createContent(id, options) {
  let doc = cts.doc(id);
  let root = doc.root.toObject();

  let source;

  // for xml we need to use xpath
  if (root && xdmp.nodeKind(root) === 'element') {
    source = root.xpath('/*:envelope/*:instance/node()');
  }
  // for json we need to return the instance
  else if (root && root.envelope && root.envelope.instance) {
    source = root.envelope.instance;
  }
  // for everything else
  else {
    source = doc;
  }

  return extractInstanceWorkOrder(source);
}

/**
 * Creates an object instance from some source document.
 * @param source  A document or node that contains
 *   data for populating a Entity
 * @return An object with extracted data and
 *   metadata about the instance.
 */
function extractInstanceWorkOrder(source) {
  // the original source documents
  let attachments = source;
    
  obj = {
    '$type': 'Entity',
    '$version': '0.0.1',
    '$attachments': null
  }
  
  obj.EntityID = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(source, "ID", true));
  obj.Location = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(source, "Location", true));
  obj.StatusHistory = getStatusHistory(obj.EntityID);
 

  // return the instance object
  return obj;
  
};

  function getStatusHistory(entityId) {
     let statusHistory =  cts.search(cts.andQuery([
       cts.collectionQuery("Collection1"),
       cts.collectionQuery("Collection2"),
       cts.elementWordQuery(xs.QName("DocumentID"), entityId),
     ]))
     
     if(fn.count(statusHistory) <= 0) return "";
     
     for (const item of statusHistory) {
   let stat = {
  '$type': 'StatusRecord',
  '$version': '0.0.1',
  }
       
   stat.StatusID = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "StatusID", true));
   stat.BeginDate = fn.replace(fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "BeginDate", true)),"/","-");
   stat.StatusFrom = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "StatusFrom", true));
   stat.StatusTo = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "StatusTo", true));
   stat.EndDate = fn.replace(fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "EndDate", true)),"/","-");
   stat.DateChanged = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "DateChanged", true));
     }
    
     return stat;
   }
```

I also tried the to iterate the call of `getStatusHistory` function and use the `xdmp.nodeInsertChild` function but it is still not working:

```js
function createContent(id, options) {
  let doc = cts.doc(id);
  let root = doc.root.toObject();

  let source;

  // for xml we need to use xpath
  if (root && xdmp.nodeKind(root) === 'element') {
    source = root.xpath('/*:envelope/*:instance/node()');
  }
  // for json we need to return the instance
  else if (root && root.envelope && root.envelope.instance) {
    source = root.envelope.instance;
  }
  // for everything else
  else {
    source = doc;
  }

  return extractInstanceWorkOrder(source);
}

/**
 * Creates an object instance from some source document.
 * @param source  A document or node that contains
 *   data for populating a Entity
 * @return An object with extracted data and
 *   metadata about the instance.
 */
function extractInstanceWorkOrder(source) {
  // the original source documents
  let attachments = source;
    
  obj = {
    '$type': 'Entity',
    '$version': '0.0.1',
    '$attachments': null
  }
  
  obj.EntityID = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(source, "ID", true));
  obj.Location = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(source, "Location", true));
  obj.StatusHistory = hl.elementText(source, "null", true);
  
    let statusHistory =  cts.search(cts.andQuery([
       cts.collectionQuery("Collection1"),
       cts.collectionQuery("Collection2"),
       cts.elementWordQuery(xs.QName("DocumentID"), obj.EntityID),
     ]))
     
 if(fn.count(statusHistory) <= 0) return "";
 for (const item of statusHistory) {
    xdmp.nodeInsertChild(obj.xpath("/*:Entity/*:Activities"),xdmp.unquote(getStatusHistory(item))); 
    }


  // return the instance object
  return obj;
  
};

  function getStatusHistory(item) {

   let stat = {
  '$type': 'StatusRecord',
  '$version': '0.0.1',
  }
       
   stat.StatusID = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "StatusID", true));
   stat.BeginDate = fn.replace(fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "BeginDate", true)),"/","-");
   stat.StatusFrom = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "StatusFrom", true));
   stat.StatusTo = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "StatusTo", true));
   stat.EndDate = fn.replace(fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "EndDate", true)),"/","-");
   stat.DateChanged = fn.normalizeSpace(hl.elementText(item, "DateChanged", true));
   
     return stat;
   }
```

**How do I get to display all the sub elements of my element `StatusHistory` for my `Entity`?**

Comment: Could you provide a sample document? You can sanitize the values if needed, but having the structure available to work with in Query Console would go a long way.